# Parse description string to populate NULL fields

Tags: parsing, ssis, etl, informix

Informix 12.10

```
tblItems
(
Type        SMALLINT,       {Precious Metal = 1, Other = 2}
Description VARCHAR,
Quantity    SMALLINT,
Name        VARCHAR,
Weight      DECIMAL(5,1),
Purity      SMALLINT,
Brand       VARCHAR,
Model       VARCHAR,
SerialNum   VARCHAR
);
```

EDIT UPDATE: Sample data below is stored in tblItems.Type and tblItems.Description. Please note that the contents in Description column are all uppercase characters and may also include punctuation character.

```
2|1LAPTOP APPLE 15.5" MODEL MACKBOOK PRO,S/N W80461WCAGX, WITH CHARGER||||||||
1|1RING 2.3PW 14K||||||||
2|DRILL RIOBY, MODEL D5521 S/N77720||||||||
2|TRIMMER TORO, MODEL 0242 S/N 66759||||||||
2|CELL SAMSUNG NOTE3, MODEL SM-N900T S/N RV8F90YLZ9W||||||||
```

I need to parse the sample item descriptions into the columns below, using the rules mentioned in the comments :

```
Quantity,      {if description string does not start with a number, then Quantity = 1}
Name,          {Always the first element if description has no quantity, second element if quantity present] 
Weight,        {Always before "PW" if Type = 1, Default to zero if Type = 2}
Purity,        {Always before "K" if Type = 1, Default to NULL if Type = 2} 
Brand,         {Always the second element in description, if present} 
Model,         {Always after "MODEL", with or without a space}
Serial Number  {Always after "S/N", with or without a space}
```

I would like to do this with an UPDATE statement, but if Informix has an import utility tool like SQL-Server's SSIS, then that could be a better option.

UPDATE, Expected Results:

```
Quantity   1               1       1        1         1
Name       LAPTOP          RING    DRILL    TRIMMER   CELL
Weight     0.0             2.3     0.0      0.0       0.0
Purity                     14
Brand      APPLE                   RIOBY    TORO      SAMSUNG
Model      MACKBOOK PRO            D5521    0242      SM-N900T
SerialNum  W8046WCAGX              77720    66759     RV8F90YLZ9W
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your tagging. It seems your question is based on using an Informix database. It is not clear where your "sample" exists. Nor does it seem that sql server plays any role here. If you want to use SSIS as an import tool, you can (I believe it can use an Informix db).

Comment: At the very top of my post it says Informix 12.10, and the sample data is beneath the table definition. If I cant accomplish what I need in Informix, then SQL-Server and SSIS could be a posible solution.

Comment: If you could also post the actual results you are expecting for the sample, it would help. Some of the rules. The `RING` entry for example, it has no brand, no model and no serial number. That being said, Informix 12.10.XC8 has the  Regex extension which could be a used for what you want. Another way would be to create 1 or more stored procedures to to the parsing of the descriprion.

Comment: I imagine I would first determine if item type is 1 or 2 for case statements, scan the entire description string, check if description[1] is a letter, or number, if description[1] is a number, check if description[2] is a number..., check spacing for BRAND, locate MODEL, S/N check for spaces before after, etc...

Comment: Does the resulting output need to be pivoted in addition to shredding the description field into discrete values?

Comment: No, just update the null columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Informix 12.10.XC8 or above, you can try using regular expressions to parse the description string (see the online [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.dbext.doc/ids_dbxt_544.htm) here).

For the serial number, for example, you can do:

```
UPDATE tblitems
SET
serialnum = 
DECODE 
(
    regex_match(description, '(.*)(S\/N)(.*)', 3)
    , 't'::BOOLEAN, regex_replace(description, '(.*)(S\/N)([[:blank:]]?)([[:alnum:]]*)(.*)', '\4', 0, 3)
    , 'f'::BOOLEAN, ''
)
```

So in the previous example I am testing if the description contains the `S/N` string and if that is true I use `regex_replace` to return the value after it, in this case the 4th matching group in the regular expression (I am not using `regex_extract` to get the value because it seems to return multiple values and I get error -686).

You can extend this approach to the rest of the columns and see if regular expressions are enough to parse the description column.

Comment: Henry Spencer's regex library is a lifesaver. I forgot to mention that the contents of the description column are all uppercase characters and may also contain punctuation marks, so the regex search type can be the default, 1 (Extended POSIX). I am also going to replace the "alnum" metacharacter with [0-9A-Z] and :punct: since alnum also includes lower case letters. It might make a performance difference since there's ~830K descriptions to pattern match. Thanks for providing the lib extension and the example.

Comment: Marques: I ignored this post for too long and SO auto-awarded half of the bounty to the wrong answer. I explicitly specified solving the objective with Informix, unless it was not possible. Your answer solved the objective. I apologize for not timely awarding the bounty to you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a SQL Server option and open to a Split/Parse function which maintains the sequence

**Example**

```
Select A.Type
      ,A.Description
      ,C.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (values ( replace(
                       replace(
                       replace(
                       replace(A.Description,',',' ')
                       ,'  ',' ')
                       ,'Model ','Model')
                       ,'S/N ','S/N')
                     ) 
             )B(CleanString)

 Cross Apply (
                Select Quantity  = IsNull(left(max(case when RetSeq=1 then RetVal end),NullIf(patindex('%[^0-9]%',max(case when RetSeq=1 then RetVal end)) -1,0)),1)
                      ,Name      = substring(max(case when RetSeq=1 then RetVal end),patindex('%[^0-9]%',max(case when RetSeq=1 then RetVal end)),charindex(' ',max(case when RetSeq=1 then RetVal end)+' ')-1)
                      ,Weight    = IIF(A.Type=2,null,try_convert(decimal(5,1),replace(max(case when RetVal like '%PW' then RetVal end),'PW','')))
                      ,Purity    = try_convert(smallint    ,replace(max(case when RetVal like '%K'  then RetVal end),'K',''))
                      ,Brand     = IIF(A.Type=1,null,max(case when RetSeq=2 then RetVal end))
                      ,Model     = replace(max(case when RetVal Like 'Model[0-9,A-Z]%' then RetVal end),'Model','')
                      ,SerialNum = replace(max(case when RetVal Like 'S/N[0-9,A-Z]%' then RetVal end),'S/N','')
                 From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](CleanString,' ') B1
             ) C
```

**Returns**

[image]

**The TVF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
```

> **EDIT - If you don't want or can't use a TVF**

**[dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=87146908cb504ac9a8e34fece060e77b)**

```
Select A.Type
      ,A.Description
      ,C.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (values ( replace(
                       replace(
                       replace(
                       replace(A.Description,',',' ')
                       ,'  ',' ')
                       ,'Model ','Model')
                       ,'S/N ','S/N')
                     ) 
             )B(CleanString)

 Cross Apply (
                Select Quantity  = IsNull(left(max(case when RetSeq=1 then RetVal end),NullIf(patindex('%[^0-9]%',max(case when RetSeq=1 then RetVal end)) -1,0)),1)
                      ,Name      = substring(max(case when RetSeq=1 then RetVal end),patindex('%[^0-9]%',max(case when RetSeq=1 then RetVal end)),charindex(' ',max(case when RetSeq=1 then RetVal end)+' ')-1)
                      ,Weight    = IIF(A.Type=2,null,try_convert(decimal(5,1),replace(max(case when RetVal like '%PW' then RetVal end),'PW','')))
                      ,Purity    = try_convert(smallint    ,replace(max(case when RetVal like '%K'  then RetVal end),'K',''))
                      ,Brand     = IIF(A.Type=1,null,max(case when RetSeq=2 then RetVal end))
                      ,Model     = replace(max(case when RetVal Like 'Model[0-9,A-Z]%' then RetVal end),'Model','')
                      ,SerialNum = replace(max(case when RetVal Like 'S/N[0-9,A-Z]%' then RetVal end),'S/N','')
                 From  (
                        Select RetSeq = row_number() over (Order By (Select null))
                              ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                        From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(CleanString,' ','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                       ) B1
             ) C
```

Comment: Luis Marques' answer of using Informix regex function is working, otherwise I would have resorted to using SSIS.